# Detecting continuous motion using millis with a PIR sensor

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to detect when continuous motion has been triggered from a PIR sensor for more than 8 seconds. Here is what I have. When sensor is LOW 'no motion...' is displayed, then short motion fires the first '< 8 sec' IF statement. When sensor returns to LOW - no motion is displayed as it should but then when motion is detected a second time, the code seems to freeze and nothing happens.

```
unsigned long startMillis;
boolean timingFlag  = false;
const int buttonPin = 2;
int buttonState = 0;

void setup() {
   pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
   Serial.begin(19200);
   delay(500);
}

void loop() {
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  if (buttonState == HIGH && millis() - startMillis <= 8000UL)
  {
    Serial.println("Motion Detected but less than 8");
    delay(1000);
    //the PIR timed out with in the three seconds so cancel timing
    timingFlag = false;    //disable timing 
  }

  if (buttonState == LOW)
  {   
    Serial.println("No Motion...");   
    delay(1000);
    timingFlag = true;     //enable timing       
  }
  //when nine seconds have gone by with consistant detection do something
  if (timingFlag == false && millis() - startMillis >= 9000UL)
  {
    //There has now been nine seconds of constant PIR detection
    Serial.println("Motion Detected and greater than 9 sec");
    delay(1000);
    //Do Something   
  }
}
```

Comment: What does me wonder: You never assign `startMillis` anywhere. Being a global variable, it will be constantly 0. I don't know about _freeze_ but it could explain _nothing happens_ after your appl. is running for more than 9 seconds, couldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one very obvious problem with your current code, as Scheff already mentioned in the comments: You never actually set your `startMillis` to anything, so they are probably (but not necessarily) always 0.

This means, that the statement `if (buttonState == HIGH && millis() - startMillis <= 8000UL)` will **always** be `false` after 8000 ms (until `millis()` flows over, after around 50 days* ), so `timingFlag` will never be reset to `false` after that. This ultimately leads to your "freezing" situation.

I tried to find a good place to set the `startMillis` in your code, but I honestly find it a little confusing, so I allowed myself to rewrite your logic, hope you don't mind. (Please note that I also changed the variable names from button to detector, since it seemed more fitting to me):

(This version triggers at the transitions from HIGH to LOW)

```
// define the threshold, after which an action shall be triggered
const int detectionThreshold = 8000;
const int detectorPin = 2;

unsigned long startTime = 0;
int lastDetectorState = LOW;

void setup() {
   pinMode(detectorPin, INPUT);
   Serial.begin(19200);
   delay(500);
}

void triggerDetectionAction(){
    // do whatever needs to be done after 8 seconds of motion in here
}

void loop() {

    int currentDetectorState = digitalRead(detectorPin);

    // if detector is low, no motion is detected
    if( currentDetectorState == LOW ){
        // when the detector is LOW, we want to check if the last state was HIGH
        // because then we just arrived at the transition from HIGH to LOW =>
        // "something was detected" to "there is no longer something detected"
        if( lastDetectorState == HIGH ){
            // then, we can get the total duration, the detection lasted
            unsigned long detectionDuration = millis() - startTime;
            // and print it for easier debugging
            Serial.print("Detection ended after ");
            Serial.print(detectionDuration);
            Serial.println(" milliseconds");

           // finally, we check if the durations was more than
           // or equal to our threshold
           if( detectionDuration >= detectionThreshold ){
               // and trigger stuff if necessary
               triggerDetectionAction();
           }
        }

        // if last detector state was LOW too, 
        // we don't want to do anything

    }else{

        // here we wan't to check for the transition of LOW to HIGH, 
        // so we check our last detector state
        if( lastDetectorState == LOW ){
            // if we caught the transition, 
            // set the start time to the current millis
            startTime = millis();

            // we could also set an indicator LED
            // or Serial.print something here
            Serial.println("Detection started");
        }

        // otherwise, we don't wan't to do anything

    }

    // finally, we save our current state into the last state, 
    // so we have it available in the next loop
    lastDetectorState = currentDetectorState;

    // do your other loop stuff here

}
```

*Please note that I couldn't test the code at the time writing, so there may be (syntax) errors*

*More about millis and overflow here: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/millis/

---

**Update**: This version will trigger immediately when the threshold is reached. It also includes an example how to trigger an action once and every loop after the threshold was reached.

```
// define the threshold, after which an action shall be triggered
const int detectionThreshold = 8000;
const int detectorPin = 2;

unsigned long startTime = 0;
int lastDetectorState = LOW;
bool actionTriggered = false;

void setup() {
   pinMode(detectorPin, INPUT);
   Serial.begin(19200);
   delay(500);
}

void triggerOnce(){
    // this will be called once, when the threshold is reached
}

void triggerEveryLoop(){
    // this will be called every loop, after the threshold was reached
    // for as long as the detector stays high
}

void loop() {

    int currentDetectorState = digitalRead(detectorPin);

    if( currentDetectorState == LOW ){

        if( lastDetectorState == HIGH ){
            // since we want to trigger immediately when the threshold is reached,
            // we actually don't need this transition any longer.
            // We can still keep it for debugging reasons thought.
            // If you don't need this, you can simply remove the entire block
            unsigned long detectionDuration = millis() - startTime;
            Serial.print("Detection ended after ");
            Serial.print(detectionDuration);
            Serial.println(" milliseconds");
        }

    }else{

        // Check for LOW => HIGH transition change
        if( lastDetectorState == LOW ){
            // if we caught the transition, 
            // set the start time to the current millis
            startTime = millis();

            // and reset the flag
            actionTriggered = false;

            // we could also set an indicator LED
            // or Serial.print something here
            Serial.println("Detection started");

        }else{

            // otherwise we want to check the duration
            unsigned long detectionDuration = millis() - startTime;

            // and trigger immediatley when the threshold is reached
            if( detectionDuration >= detectionThreshold ){

               // as long as it wasn't already triggered before
               if( !actionTriggered ){

                   Serial.println("Threshold reached, triggering");

                   // now we also need to set a flag, so we know we already triggerd this action once
                   actionTriggered = true;

                   triggerOnce();
               }

               // we can also do something every loop
               // this can be handy for e.g. blinking a light or playing a sound or something
               triggerEveryLoop();

           }

        }

    }

    // finally, we save our current state into the last state, 
    // so we have it available in the next loop
    lastDetectorState = currentDetectorState;

    // do your other loop stuff here

}
```

Comment: Although this works perfectly as designed, I have one request. Is it possible to interrupt immediately after 8 seconds has passed to perform triggerDetectionAction? Otherwise, we have to wait until no motion is performed before we get the detectionDuration.

Comment: Of course, I updated my answer to include both versions.